# Why does a nucleophile have to be replaced by a nucleophile?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, nucleophilic-substitution, electronegativity, nucleophilicity

I'm a highschool student for context and I was thinking why does a nucleophile need to be replaced by a nucleophile in a nucleophilic substitution reaction -  why doesn't it just replace one of the $\ce{C-H}$ bonds instead. Asked my teacher and she said, "stability". I have no clue what that means and I would like to understand what exactly this term means.

Comment: o.O Nucleophile replaces a leaving group, which has to good enough to be substituted. You thought what would leave in your scenario?

Comment: @Mithoron I thought the carbon-hydrogen bond would break and the hydrogen would leave.

Comment: Hydrogen *anion* would leave - it's one of worst leaving groups. No way it would happen, unless something would accept it at the same time.

Comment: BTW why didn't you consider that C-C bond could be broken? It's actually more likely scenario, but still a rare thing.

Comment: "Stability" in this context refers to a bond's resistance to breaking. A C-H bond is way more stable than a C-X bond, and therefore way more resistant to breaking. In other words, C-X bonds are easier to break because they are more unstable.

Comment: How can a *nucleophile* be *replaced* by *another nucleophile*? Something's highly inaccurate here with your terminology. Is it by any chance that you missed out on the term *electrophile* / *electrophilic nature*?

Comment: It is an ionic reaction. The Original compound has a polar bond with a negative leaving group and a partial positive charge on the carbon. The nucleophile approaches the carbon forming a bond while the bond to the original nucleophile breaks. [SN2 mechanism]. C-H and C-C bonds are usually nonpolar so they do not participate directly in ionic reactions. The actual reaction depends on the bond strengths, concentrations and reaction conditions.

Comment: @jimchmst Ty that makes perfect sense.